# T-SQL Conversion Failed when converting date/or time from character string

Tags: t-sql, datetime, perfmon

Perfmon isn't so kind with the way it creates the database when logging directly to SQL:

[image]

`select top 1 Convert(datetime, CounterDateTime) from CounterData`

returns

`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

The value of that cell is "2012-01-25 14:12:10.802". What is the proper way to convert this to a datetime field during selection?

Comment: did you try using CAST(CounterDateTime as DateTime)?

Comment: Which Version of MS SQL are you using? it works in MS SQL 2008 

CREATE TABLE #Table (CounterDateTime char(24))
INSERT INTO #Table(CounterDateTime) 
 SELECT '2012-01-25 14:12:10.802'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CounterDateTime) FROM #Table

Comment: @Akhil: SQL Server 2008 R2 (Added an answer with a workaround)

Answer (score 1):

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(CounterDateTime, 1, 23), 102)
```

Comment: Found this answer to generate a Deterministic result when enclosed in function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the following works (instead of the `CHAR(24)` it is):

`select top 1 Cast(Cast(CounterDateTime as CHAR(23)) as datetime) from CounterData`

Hoping there is a better solution though.

Answer (score 0):

No better answer but this makes the taste a trifle less bitter.

**CAST(CAST(CounterData.CounterDateTime AS CHAR(NN)) AS DATETIME) AS CounterDateTime**

Also truncates the value so that additional T-SQL DateTime truncation to the minute, hour, etc is not needed.